# How can I know when the mobile keyboard is open in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the Textfield below which has the Autofocus attribute,i want to know if there is a way to know when the keyboard is open in mobile view and store it in a boolean variable.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you would need to access the "device" for native functionality of status on user device? Alternative: program in your *own* ui for input.

Comment: i want to know when the keyboard is open. I thought with refs but i didnt figure out how to do it

Answer (score 2):

```
const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      () => {
        setKeyboardVisible(true); // or some other action
      }
    );
    const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      () => {
        setKeyboardVisible(false); // or some other action
      }
    );

    return () => {
      keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
      keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Hi when i wrote "Keyboard.addListener" the error is Keyboard.addListener is not a function.. and when i wrote with lowerCase "keyboard.addListener" the error is keyboard is not defined. Any idea?

Comment: maybe this works only in react-native ? I am using React

Comment: Sometimes you have to come at the answer you really want "sideways" on StackOverlfow.  Consider asking a new question focusing on knowing the state of the mobile keyboard using just HTML/CSS.  Once you know how do that at the basic level, then ask a separate question on how to use that feature with React and Material-UI.